How to get a true scatterplot matrix from GGally?
I am using ggpairs from the GGally package to make a scatterplot matrix by setting upper = list(continuous = "points").
I realized that the density plot along the diagonal actually takes over the y-axis limit for the first row of plots.  In other words, the y-axis ticks for that first row are actually wrong.  They should be 9-11 instead of 0-0.6.
How can I get valid ticks?  I tried to set the diagonals to "blank", but this erases the ticks altogether.  I also tried to specify a custom function, but I can't figure out the syntax.
library(tidyverse)
library(GGally)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'GGally':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2

rn <- partial(runif, min = -1, max = 1)

tibble(ten = 10 + rn(100), twenty = 20 + rn(100), thirty = 30 + rn(100)) |> 
  ggpairs(
    upper = list(continuous = "points"), 
    #diag = list(continuous = function(data, mapping) {ggplot(data) + aes(x, y) + geom_point()}))
    #diag = list(continuous = function(data, mapping) {ggplot(data) + mapping + geom_point()}))
  )


Created on 2024-07-16 with reprex v2.1.0

I don't see an (easy) option to achieve your desired result using ggpairs. But one option would be to build your pairsplot from scratch using ggmatrix which allows for more fine-control over the scales and axes.
Basically I use layer_scales to get the limits of the scales for the density plots, then do some rescaling to get the x axis breaks and labels for the y axis too.
library(tidyverse)
library(GGally)

set.seed(123)

rn <- partial(runif, min = -1, max = 1)

dat <- tibble(ten = 10 + rn(100), twenty = 20 + rn(100), thirty = 30 + rn(100))

p_list <- expand.grid(
  x = names(dat), y = names(dat),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) |>
  purrr::pmap(
    \(x, y) {
      geom_layer <- if (x == y) {
        geom_density(aes(.data[[x]]))
      } else {
        geom_point(aes(.data[[x]], .data[[y]]))
      }
      p <- ggplot(dat) +
        geom_layer

      if (x == y) {
        from <- layer_scales(p)$y$get_limits()
        to <- layer_scales(p)$x$get_limits()

        p <- p +
          scale_y_continuous(
            breaks = scales::rescale(
              scales::breaks_extended()(to),
              from = to,
              to = from
            ),
            labels = \(x) {
              scales::rescale(
                x,
                from = from,
                to = to
              )
            }
          )
      }

      p
    }
  )

ggmatrix(
  p_list, nrow = 3, ncol = 3,
  xAxisLabels = names(dat), 
  yAxisLabels = names(dat)
)


